# Is it possible to make a more vectorized solution to this?

Tags: matlab

I'm supposed to do a really simple blurring algorithm for an image matrix in MATLAB. The purpose of the function is to take a m x n matrix, and take each elements and its neighbouring elements average to make a "blurred" m-2 x n-2.

My current code looks like this:

```
function [out] = blurring(anImage)
 tic;
 [ny nx] = size(anImage);
 out = zeros(ny-2, nx-2);
 yv = 1:ny-2;
 xv = 1:nx-2;
 for iy=0:2;
  for ix = 0:2;
  out = out + anImage(yv + iy, xv + ix);
  end
 end
 out = out/9;
 toc
end
```

The goal would be to completely **vectorize** my solution by eliminating the iteration part of the code. I don't mind, if that is only possible making the program a bit slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have implemented is a special case of convolution:

```
conv2(anImage,ones(3,3)./9,'valid')
```

Comment: No need for the `.` :-)